# iOS App- LaunchScreen.storyboard displays white on ios 14.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have Xcode version 12.0.1.
I have run the app on simulator with ios 14, the launch screen working fine it shows the image I want to show(splash Screen), but when I run the app on real device which has ios 14.2 the launch screen just appeared to be white. can some one help me with this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faced the same problem. The issue was the size of the image used in the launch screen storyboard. This lead to the whole launch screen just being black.

**Solution 1:**
What fixed it in our case was:

1. Choose a smaller size image
2. Delete App from device/simulator (Sometimes required)
3. Restart device/simulator (Sometimes required)

**The main reason is the larger image so just replace it with a smaller one.**

**Solution 2:**
Place your splash screen image outside the Images.xcassets folder. (But the issue with this approach is if you are supporting Dark Mode then it's not possible anymore to set a different image for dark and light mode.)

Comment: Same issue here - it was only an issue on a real device (not simulator) with iOS 14.2. I didn't try Solution 1, but Solution 2 solved the problem for me immediately.