# Flutter ios app show White screen in release mode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, flutter

[FLUTTER]
Can anyone help me, my app works fine on debug mode, but on release mode i got a white empty screen.

I tried many times :
flluter clean

Flutter doctor > Any issue

[ERROR]
2021-01-31 19:37:54.730451+0100 Runner[29477:2429346] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError: Value not in range: -1

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried running the program from XCode? What is the output there?

Comment: Yes  tried from XCode, works fine on Simulator and Iphone Device
.But When i archive and export the IPA, it shows me a empty white screen.

Comment: I tried to change the schem from Debug to Release
And with XCode, it sows me this error:

[ERROR] 2021-01-31 19:37:54.730451+0100 Runner[29477:2429346] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError: Value not in range: -1

Comment: It sounds like this issue is coming from your own code somewhere. Try running the app while monitoring your logs through the device console and see if you can narrow down where.

Comment: You have an error in your code, probably in a method where you use `index` in a certain list. In release mode the red screen you'd normally get in debug mode will turn into white screens.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65034669/2781088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESOLVED]

I found a bug in the main.dart code.

Thank you for your response.